# Order by empty custom field

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop, query, order

I order my posts by custom field **faq-order**. That's work for me:

```
$faqArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'faq',
    'meta_key' => 'faq-order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);

$faq = new WP_Query($faqArgs);
```

But post disappear from result response if those field **faq-order** is empty. How can I fix it? How can I use default value (for example 0), if that field is empty?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for that:

### 1. Make sure that all posts have that field set.

You can do this easily - just use [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook and set it to default value. (You should also add default values for already existing posts that don't have that field set.)

### 2. Use a little bit modified query

```
$faqArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'faq',
    'meta_key' => 'faq-order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'faq-order', 
            'value' => 'bug #23268', 
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
$faq = new WP_Query($faqArgs);
```